# Mysql - insert and empty join

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a python application to register the working hours by an RFID reader on Raspberry Pi connected to mysql database. I have 3 tables:

- Employee (with UserId, Name, Surname, etc)
- Connection (with key_id, UserId)
- Registration (with UserId, Date, Time)

I would like to reuse the RFID cards, so the personal name is not directly connected to the key_id of the RFID card: in this way just changing the relation `key_id <--> UserId` on `Connection` table I can reuse it withous losing the past (I check the working hours by User_Id).

To write on Registration table I'm usign the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Registration (key_id, User_Id, TimbraData,TimbraStato,TimbraHH) 
SELECT 'XXXXXXXX',Connection.User_Id,'2024-03-19','E','18.40' 
from Connection 
where Connection.key_id='XXXXXXXX'
```

This is writing the record on Registration table (the key_id 'XXXXXXXX' is coming from RFID reader)

Question: if I have a new card not yet assigned (on Connction table the key_id is missing) I would like to write on Registration table a record where User_Id is NULL. Whith my query if Connection.key_id='XXXXXXXX' don't match is not writing any record.

Of course if you have other ideas to match the target are very welcome!

Thak you very much!

```
INSERT INTO Registration (key_id, User_Id, TimbraData,TimbraStato,TimbraHH) 
SELECT 'XXXXXXXX',Connection.User_Id,'2024-03-19','E','18.40' 
from Connection 
where Connection.key_id='XXXXXXXX'
```

This is writing this record:

```
 key_id    User_Id    TimbraData TimbraStato  TimbraHH
XXXXXXXX  myuserid  2024-03-19       E          18.40
```

If the Connection.key_id='XXXXXXXX' don't match I would like a record like this:

```
 key_id    User_Id    TimbraData TimbraStato  TimbraHH
XXXXXXXX     NULL     2024-03-19       E          18.40
```

Comment: Just of note, keep in mind that there are many types of cards, some with encryption standards, but be aware you assume someone will never accidently or on purpose use a device that fits outside of the xxxxxxx scope, perhaps with more characters or even alphanumeric when you are expecting integer.  And it seems like you want the Index to be the Id, but you might be better using Primary Keys with Auto Increment that happen to have the key_id value in another colum instead, so that if you get a many of them it can sequence them better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, use a subquery in the `VALUES` list.

```
INSERT INTO Registration (key_id, User_Id, TimbraData,TimbraStato,TimbraHH) 
VALUES ('XXXXXXXX', (
    SELECT User_Id 
    FROM Connection 
    WHERE key_id='XXXXXXXX'
),'2024-03-19','E','18.40')
```

If the subquery has no matching row, its value will be `NULL`.

This is a reasonable approach because you only need one column from the `Connection` table.